# How do I minify javascript files using RequireJS in AppHarbor?

Tags: build, requirejs, appharbor

In my Release post-build event I [run node.exe in order to minify and combine my javascript files with RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html). This creates new folders and minified files inside my website folders which I then reference in my HTML when debugging is disabled.

node.exe is contained within my source control, and building this on my local machine works fine.

When this is built on AppHarbor, I am getting the following error straight after running

```
"node.exe <<PATH TO r.js>> -o <<PATH TO app.build.js>>"
```

:

```
fs.js:520
    return binding.lstat(pathModule._makeLong(path));
                   ^
EXEC : error : EPERM, operation not permitted 'D:\temp'
```

Is this because I don't have permission to create folders/files on AppHarbor? How would I be able to get around this and build the minified files?

I don't want to have the minified files pre-built into source control.

Answer (score 1):

From AppHarbor FAQ:
http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions

> My application cannot write files
>   By default, applications deployed on AppHarbor can only write to the App_Data folder.
>   You can enable write access to the entire application directory application settings.
>   Note that changes (both to App_Data and the rest of the application directory) are not persisted between deploys and you should only use it for caching and other temporary uses.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: I enabled "File system write access" for the application, yet the same error is still coming back...

Comment: You can create folders during the build process, but only within the build-folders.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to resolve this is probably reproduce the AppHarbor build locally and ensure that everything goes where it's supposed to go. This is what you want to run: `msbuild solution.sln /p:Configuration=Release /property:OutDir=C:\temp`. There's more in the FAQ: http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions